Coravel starting too late
I created a windows service using AddWindowsService(). This service should be executed daily at 4:05 AM. For this case, I use Coravel. This is how I configured Coravel:
builder.Services.AddScheduler();

var app = builder.Build();

app.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
{
    scheduler.Schedule<DataConsistencyCheckService>()
    .DailyAt(04, 05)
    .PreventOverlapping(nameof(DataConsistencyCheckService))
    .RunOnceAtStart();
});

I found in the documentation (https://docs.coravel.net/Scheduler/#intervals), that this would be UTC. I'm in the time zone GMT. This is two hours ahead of UTC. Means 4:05 AM in UTC is 2:05 AM.
But Coravel executes this task two hours later on 6:05 AM. Why is coravel executing this task to late?
As workaround I use Zoned(TimeZoneInfo.Local). But I want to know this behaviour. I think this is not working correctly. Am I wrong?
